# Do you have examples where clang-tidy can break the code?

Tags: c++, clang-tidy

Can clang-tidy break the code (when you apply the `-fix` option)?

For example, it can reorder headers and cause some wrong order of included symbols.

But maybe you have more examples where it can break?